# create an array of exact matches between an array of phrases and a string variable

Tags: javascript

I have an array of phrases like :

```
let structures = ['to earth' ,'to protect you', 'i do', 'i love', 'i was sent', 'i want'];
```

And I have a string variable like:

```
let speechResult = 'i was sent to mars and earth i wanted i love'
```

I want to create a new array based on the exact match of phrases in the array and the string variable.

The expected result of above example would be:

```
let newArr = [ 'i was sent', 'i love'];
```

**Note**: the performance of the code is important!

**Update:** I did this but this has two issues :

-First: I didn't get the order of the expected result.

-Second: There are no exact matches so I didn't get the expected result at all.

```js
    let structures = ['to earth' ,'to protect you', 'i do', 'i love', 'i was sent', 'i want'];
    
    let speechResult = 'i was sent to mars and earth i wanted i love'
    let newArr = [];
    
    for(let i = 0; i < structures.length; i++ ){
    
        if(speechResult.includes(structures[i])){
        
           newArr.push(structures[i]);
        
        }
    }
    
    
    console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: `.match(new RegExp(\`\\b(${structures.map(e => e.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join("|")})\\b\`, "g"))`

Comment: What do you mean by *"the performance of the code is important"* and how do you measure it? @ASDF, could you please explain the solution above? And maybe post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically quite easy to solve by filtering:

```js
let structures = ['to earth' ,'to protect you', 'i do', 'i love', 'i was sent', 'i want'];
let speechResult = 'i was sent to mars and earth i wanted i love'

const newArr = structures.filter((structure) => speechResult.includes(structure));

console.log(newArr);
```

But as you can see, also *"i want"* is includes (since speechResult contains "i wanted"). Therefore, we have to use a regexp to exclude such partial hits:

```js
let structures = ['to earth' ,'to protect you', 'i do', 'i love', 'i was sent', 'i want'];
let speechResult = 'i was sent to mars and earth i wanted i love'

const newArr = structures.filter((structure) => {
  const rg = new RegExp(`(${structure})(?![a-z]+)`,'gi');
  return speechResult.match(rg);
});

console.log(newArr);
```

That will give us the correct result (quite efficiently, I'd say).

Answer (score 1):

`filter()` iterates through each element in the array and returns only those elements that match a criteria, seen in the `return` statement.

`idx` is the starting index of each element in the string. If the element isn't in the string it returns -1.

`nex` is the index in the string of the last character of the element. It's used to make sure the element doesn't end mid-word in the string.

Finally, `sort()` reorders the elements in the order they appear in the string.

```js
let arr = ['to earth' ,'to protect you', 'i do', 'i love', 'i was sent', 'i want']
let str = 'i was sent to mars and earth i wanted i love'

let res = arr.filter(el => {
    let idx = str.indexOf(el)
    let nex = idx + el.length
    return idx > -1 && (str.length === nex || str[nex] === " ")
}).sort((a,b) => str.indexOf(a) - str.indexOf(b))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: How is this brilliant, if it doesn't even give you the result you want?

Comment: @SaraRee see my edit, I tried to explain the important parts

Comment: @SaraRee also, see my code edit to sort them in the order they appear in the string, if that's important to you.

Comment: @ASDFGerte the sorting? That's an easy fix.

Comment: Now it gives the desires result, in O(n²log(n)). But i'm not really complaining about your answer, more, that the question went unclear for me, the moment the wrong order here was "brilliant" - i thought i may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206246/discussion-between-tao-and-symlink).